# Compare matrices multiplication

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I must multiply a matrix by itself until the matrix in some degree would not be equal to one of the preceding matrices. Then I need to get the values of degrees in which the matrices are equal. The number of rows and columns are equal. The matrix is stored in a two-dimensional array. Values are 0 or 1. What is the best way to check for equality with the previous matrices? I tried to use `vector` to store matrices:

```
vector<int[5][5]> m;
```

but I got an error `cannot convert from 'const int [5][5]' to 'int [5][5]'`.

Waiting for an advice.

Comment: You should probably post the code fragment that causes the compile error.

Comment: By 'in some degree' do you mean rotation? (Or have I just forgotten the term?) Are these always 5x5 square matrices?

Comment: I'm using "vector<int[5][5]> m;" and get error. Maybe there is another way to store matrices? Matrices can be 3x3 or 4x4... This is not important.

Comment: vector<int[5][5]> is the cause of your compiler error - you can't do that.  Make a small matrix class that stores your data array and then use that in the vector.

Comment: Sure - I was really asking if they were square matrices to try and understand what you meant by degrees, but then I spotted you had 5x5 in the error message.

Comment: The cause of that error is almost certainly that you were trying to convert something `const` to something non-`const`, as the error says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use [boost](http://www.boost.org/), look at the boost [Matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm) class:

It seems to be missing an `==` operator, but it's easy to add:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const matrix<T>& m, const matrix<T>& n)
{
  bool returnValue = 
    (m.size1() == n.size1()) &&
    (m.size2() == n.size2());

  if (returnValue)
  {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; returnValue && i < m.size1(); ++i)
    {
      for (unsigned int j = 0; returnValue && j < m.size2(); ++j)
      {
        returnValue &= m(i,j) == n(i,j);
      }
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

And used like so:

```
int main ()
{

  matrix<double> m (3, 3);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m.size1(); ++ i)
  {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m.size2(); ++ j)
    {
      m (i, j) = 3 * i + j;
    }
  }
  std::cout << m << std::endl;

  matrix<double> n (3, 3);

  std::cout << (m == n) << std::endl;
  std::cout << (m == m) << std::endl;
}
```

[[Code]](http://codepad.org/xEFFJETW)

Comment: The `operator==` is missing because equality comparison of floating point (target of the library) makes little or no sense. In any case, there is a `ublas::detail::equals` (weak equality) that is safer to use because it allows for thresholds. For example `ublas::detail::equals(m1, m2, 1.e-6, 0.)`. Or if one insists `template<class M1, class M2> bool operator==(M1 const& m1, M2 const& m2){return detail::equals(m1, m2, std::numeric_limits<M1::value_type>::epsilon(), std::numeric_limits<M1::value_type>::min());}` (Also, throws if sizes are incompatible which maybe or maybe not a desired behavior)

Comment: in new gcc parlance (version > 5 and/or C++11), the `typename` keyword is mandatory, and the above function should rather be: `template<class M1, class M2> bool operator==(M1 const& m1, M2 const& m2) { return detail::equals(m1,m2, std::numeric_limits<typename M1::value_type>::epsilon(),std::numeric_limits<typename M1::value_type>::min()); }    You will note the `typename` keyword when using numeric_limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with `vector`, you probably want `vector < vector < int > >`, i.e. a vector of vectors of ints (i.e. kind of 2-dimensional vector).

`vector<int[5][5]>` would (if it worked) declare a vector of 2-dimensional 5x5-`int`-arrays.